# trying to make an html buttom run a python script in flask using posts

Tags: python

pretty much what the title says... I can see that it is posting but its not implemented it.  Overall I'm trying to make a switch for LED lights on a raspberry pi through a web server.  Does anyone see a mistake in the code below?  Been trying to figure it out for the last couple of hours and I'm getting no where. I can post the other files of code if need be.

By the way this is the first time I've worked with anything like this.

```
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template, url_for, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
from lights import lightToggle

r = 6
g = 5
b = 13

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(g, GPIO.OUT) # BCM pin 5: Green
GPIO.setup(r, GPIO.OUT) # BCM pin 6: Red
GPIO.setup(b, GPIO.OUT) # BCM pin 13: Blue


lights = {'Red': [r, GPIO.input(r)], 'Green': [g, GPIO.input(g)], 'Blue': [b, GPIO.input(g)]}




leds = [{'led': '0'}, {'led': '1'}, {'led': '2'}]
bright = 0
@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/lights', methods=['GET'])
def returnLEDS():
    return jsonify({'leds': leds})

@app.route('/on', methods=["GET","POST"])
def webPage():
    print "hello"
    try:
        if request.method=="POST":  
            attempted_username = request.form['username']
            lightToggle(attempted_username)
        if attempted_username == "red":
            return redirect(url_for('/index'))

    except Exeption as e:
        return render_template('on.html')    

@app.route('/lights/<string:led>', methods=['GET'])
def returnOne(v):
    tempList = [x for x in leds if leds['led'] == v]
    return jsonify({'led': tempList[0]})

#@app.route('/lights', methods=['POST'])
#def redOn():
#    leds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='10.0.0.209', port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: Could you add more information about what exactly isn't working? You say you can see that it is posting; which of your many routes is it posting to? What does your flask code do when the post happens? What do you _want_ your flask code to do when the post happens?

Comment: when the post happens I want to it to trigger a function that turns on the LED light.  it is not doing that. but you can see on the command prompt that it executed it. @Hamms

Comment: What route is it posting to?